# Как обратить к элементу массива в ассемблере

Tags: массивы, ассемблер, сегментация

моя задача Задать одномерный массив (элементы массива – двухбайтовые), состоящий
из N элементов. Заполнить массив константами. Переместить в другую
область памяти элементы с четными номерами.
для понимания как это можно реализовать я написала такой код для того чтобы понять как вообще обратиться к элементу массива в ассемблере

```
org 100h  
mas dw 0,1,2,3,4
mov si,6
mov ax,mas [si]
ret
```

мне нужно, чтобы вывелась тройка, но выводится другое число.
Кажется, здесь нет сегмента данных, не понимаю как он прописывается ,подскажите, пожалуйста :с

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это досовский com файл, то не будет отдельно сегментов кода, данных, стека, а будет все в одном сегменте (модель памяти tiny).

Обращение к элементу правильное, но программа не рабочая, т.к. в com файле исполнение начинается с самого начала файла, а в начале файла идут данные, которые начнут исполняться как код. Для исправления можно, например, переместить объявление массива после `ret`.

Для проверки работоспособности можно хранить в массиве не просто числа, а коды символов, и вывести на экран символ, прочитанный с адреса `mas + 6`:

```
org 100h

mov si, 6
mov dx, [mas + si] ; подправлено под диалект fasm. То же самое, что mas[si] в некоторых других диалектах
mov ah, 2
int 21h  ; функция 2 прерывания 21h - вывод на экран символа из регистра dl
ret

mas dw '0', '1', '2', '3', '4'
```

[image: Скриншот]